# Find the last of input type="file"

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

The whole html: https://dpaste.com/82768UN7D

There are several such elements:

```
<input type="file" name="images_responsiveimage_related-0-responsive_image" accept="image/*" id="id_images_responsiveimage_related-0-responsive_image"></p>
```

I want to find the last of them via Python's Selenium:

```
last_input_type_xpath = "//input[@type='file'][last()]"
input_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

I get NoSuchElementException.

Comment: input_element  = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@type='file']')[-1]   Try this and let me know did it help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **xpath** seems wrong.To get the last input file Try that

```
(//input[@type='file'])[last()]
```

Ideally you should wait for the element use webdriverwait

```
input_element=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//input[@type='file'])[last()]")))
```

You need to import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```